# User input number of days and generate the start date and end date using python

Tags: python, django

I'm python beginner.

I need a code in which there is a text field that takes the number of days from user and a start date as well. Based on the number of days it should calculate the end date.

If the user specifies the start date and end date it should count the number of days and display it in the corresponding field. I need the code in django views.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! But SO is not a coding site . It's here to help you get unstuck form a specific problem. What have you tried ? Show us some actual code of your models, your trials and errors.

Comment: How it is supposed to calculate the end date? Could you please explain what did you tried, and how it failed?

Comment: i need to pass the startdate through url and the end date must be saved to my db. like <a href="localhost:8000/Date?start_date=26/6/2014&days=5">, so it has to calculate the end date based on no.of days

Comment: finally got it using strptime and timedelta... Thanks @cor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at timedelta options [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html). You can do things like that:

```
from datetime import date,timedelta

myday = mifirstday+timedelta(weeks=1)
myday = mifirstday+timedelta(days=4)
```

Comment: day1 = req_startdate
  day2 = req_enddate
  day1 = datetime.strptime(day1, '%Y:%m:%d').date()
  day2 = datetime.strptime(day2, '%Y:%m:%d').date()
  req_enddate = day2 - day1
  return HttpResponse(req_enddate)

Comment: Ok, I have deleted the answer thinking that it wasn't what you were looking for.

Comment: @Krish, I don't understand the downvote. Check it if it is the correct answer.